# Using point shapefile as training sample in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to do random forest classification. I prepared a point shape file with training sample outside GEE, the true land cover class being in the field `code`. Then I imported the shapefile in GEE (as `training_shape`) and wanted to sample a raster image (`input_img_m`) in order to get the raster values for each point and thus generate training sample for classification.

However, I am not sure which tool to use. I tried with `.sampleRegions`. I know this is working exactly I want it with polygons and I hoped it will work with point as well. But after 20 min of processing I get error: `Error: Unable to export features with null geometry.`

This is part of my script:

```
var training = input_img_m.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the point FeatureCollection.
  collection: training_shape,
  // We'll classify on 'code"
  properties: ['code'],
  // Set the scale to get Sentinel-2 pixels.
  scale: 10,
  tileScale: 4
});


Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: training,
  description:'exportToTableAsset',
  assetId: 'samples',
});
```

What is a better way to use training sample shapefile for classification in GEE if the geometry of the shapes is point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sampleRegions()` will by default omit the geometries, and like you might guess from the error message, `Export.table.toAsset()` expects the features to contain geometries. You can explicitly include the geometries by setting the `geometries` property in `sampleRegions()` to `true`.

```
var training = input_img_m.sampleRegions({
  collection: training_shape,
  properties: ['code'],
  scale: 10,
  tileScale: 4,
  geometries: true
})
```